# QWidget::setCursor on MacOS X does not work second time

Tags: macos, qt, cursor, qwidget

Qt 5.0.1, MacOS X 10.8.3
Setting cursor from resource QPixmap works only first time. All consequent calls to QWidget::setCursor for another cursors created from QPixmap apply first cursor.

Same if calling unsetCursor between different setCursor calls. Same if using QApplication's override cursor.

Additionally OS X ignores Qt hotspot - it is always (0,0)

Cursors created from predefined shapes set work OK. On Windows everything is OK

Has anyone guess what to do with this? Thanks